# Dynamic range of an ADC is 6n dB?

Tags: adc

In the book *Art of Electronics*, it says that an ADC with a sampling depth of n bits has a dynamic range of 6n dB. Where does 6n dB come from?

Comment: Adding one bit doubles the number of levels. 6dB is a factor of 2. Hence, you get 6dB every time you add a bit.

Comment: I think you mean 6n dB, not 6 ndB, which would be nanodecibels.

Comment: Yes @Hearth. Thanks user, makes sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\$20 \log_{10}2 \approx 6\$

Each bit added to the width of the output of an ADC increases the dynamic range by a factor of 2. Therefore it increases the dynamic range by 6 dB.